# Evaluation of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I have to evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x^{2}-x+1}{x-1}dx$$
So I divide it in:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2}-x+1}{x-1}dx+\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x^{2}-x+1}{x-1}dx$$ and the integral is equal to:
$$\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\ln (\left | x-1 \right |)$$ Then I substitute 1 as :$$\lim_{a \to 1^{-}} \left [  \frac{x^{2}}{2}+\ln (\left | x-1 \right |)\right ]_{0}^{a}+\lim_{b \to 1^{+}} \left [  \frac{x^{2}}{2}+\ln (\left | x-1 \right |)\right ]_{b}^{2}$$
But then I got indefinite term.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Notice that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\ln|x-1|=-\infty$

Comment: @jl00 yes and because of that I will have indefinite term, or Am I wrong?

Comment: You are integrating over an interval from $0$ to $2$ a function which is not defined at $x=1$ due to the denominator. An integral can be interpreted as the area under your function and thus as the function tends towards infinity at $x = 1$ so does the area underneath it and the integral is not defined.

Comment: @DinnoKoluh Because of x=1 I substitute it to a and b, and then I want to evaluate the limit, it is equal to −∞ in both case, so I have  indefinite term. Am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: Yes, you could interpret it as you stated.

Comment: @DinnoKoluh but then what is the result?

Comment: You could also consider the Cauchy Principle Value of the integral for which it is easy to show is equal to $2$. Otherwise you get $\infty - \infty$, and so the integral does not converge.

Comment: @Shelley There is no result. The integral is divergent and it is not defined at that interval. If you would integrate it at some other interval e.g. [2,5] you would get an answer but as long as you have the 1 in your interval the integral will be divergent and thus have no solution.

Comment: @jl00 Can you show me the Cauchy Principle Value of the integral? How it will look like?

Comment: @DinnoKoluh okay, thanks

Comment: Don't do this because it is bad math, but you can guess that the C.P.V. is $2$ given that $2+(\lim_{a\rightarrow 1}\ln|a-1| - \lim_{b\rightarrow 1}\ln|b-1|)=2+\lim_{a\rightarrow 1} (\ln|a-1|-\ln|a-1|)=2+\lim_{a\to 1}0 = 2$ (Notice that this makes no sense and you should NOT do this)

Comment: @jl00 but do not you think that I tried it in the solution above?

Comment: Are you seeing this problem in the context of calculus (usually "calculus of a single real variable") or a setting that depends on calculus; or are you seeing this problem in the contest of real analysis (where the subject matter typically includes measures, $L^p$ spaces, modes of convergence, and elementary results about Hilbert and Banach spaces)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) and a small $u$-substitution will help you see that this integral should diverge, so its value does not exist.

$$  \frac{x^2 - x + 1}{x-1} = x + \frac{1}{x-1}  $$
so
$$  \int_0^2 \frac{x^2 - x + 1}{x-1} \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^2 x + \frac{1}{x-1} \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}  $$
Linearity of the integral gives
$$  \int_0^2 x + \frac{1}{x-1} \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^2 x \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_0^2 \frac{1}{x-1} \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}  $$
The first integral, as you have shown, is easy.  Let's apply a substitution, $x \mapsto u+1$ so $\mathrm{d}x \mapsto \mathrm{d}u$, to the second integral.
$$  \int_0^2 x \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_0^2 \frac{1}{x-1} \,\mathrm{d}x = \left. \frac{x^2}{2} \right|_{x=0}^2 + \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{u} \,\mathrm{d}u  \text{.}  $$
The evaluation for the first term is easy.  (Perhaps we already realize that the integral has no hope of converging by the $p$-test.)  But we should recognize that the integral cannot be approached directly with the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Corollary) because its integrand is not continuous (at $x = 0$).  So we break it at $x = 0$.
$$ \left. \frac{x^2}{2} \right|_{x=0}^2 + \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{u} \,\mathrm{d}u = 2 + \int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{u} \,\mathrm{d}u + \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{u} \,\mathrm{d}u  \text{.}  $$
An antiderivative of $1/x$ is $\ln |x|$.  So we have \begin{align*}
2 + \int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{u} \,\mathrm{d}u + \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{u} \,\mathrm{d}u &= 2 + \Bigl. \ln |u| \Bigr|_{-1}^0 + \Bigl. \ln |u| \Bigr|_{0}^1  \\
    &= 2 + (\lim_{u \rightarrow 0^-}\ln |u| - \ln 1) + (\ln 1 - \lim_{u \rightarrow 0^+} \ln |u|)  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
Since the first limit does not exist, the integral from which it comes does not converge and so the original integral does not converge.  The value of that integral does not exist.  Similarly, the second limit does not exist, the integral from which it comes does not converge, and the original integral does not converge.

As noted in comments, the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Examples) of this integral is computed by using the fact that $\frac{1}{u}$ is an odd function to say that the integral $\int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{u} \,\mathrm{d}u = 0$ for all $a > 0$.  We have the case $a = 1$ above.  If we had been asked to compute a Cauchy Principal Value, we would have 
$$  \mathrm{PV}\int_0^2 \frac{x^2 - x + 1}{x-1} \,\mathrm{d}x = \cdots = 2  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Why do you use as your boundries -1 and 0 and then 0,1

Comment: @Shelley : "break it at $x = 0$".

Comment: okay, thanks, I understand the solution but I think that in my case, it should be −∞

Comment: @Shelley : No.  One $-\infty$ appears with sign $+$ and one $-\infty$ appears with sign $-$ because they are at opposite ends of their intervals.

Comment: @Shelley : If we put them where they go in my evaluation, you have $2 + (-\infty - \ln 1) + (\ln 1 - -\infty)$.  They do not appear in this sum of terms with the same signs.

Comment: okay, so my mistake was that I did not divide ln(x) in parts, thanks I understand it now

Comment: @Shelley : $1/u$ is negative for all $u$ in $[-1,0)$, so its integral must be negative.  $1/u$ is positive for all $u$ in $(0,1]$, so its integral must be positive.  These two infinities must have opposite signs.

Comment: I understand it now, thanks a lot

Comment: @Shelley : You *did* divide the log into parts.  That is why you have a limit as $x \rightarrow 1^+$ and another as $x \rightarrow 1^-$.  You are correctly dealing with the improper integral.

Comment: okay and then I have to divide ln(x) because it breaks at zero all the time?

Comment: @Shelley : You have to break the inte*grand* $1/u$ at $u = 0$ because it is not continuous at $u = 1$.  You must split the interval of an integral at each point of discontinuity of the integrand (and, with full care, approach the break using a one-sided limit).

Comment: *Since the first limit does not exist, the integral from which it comes does not converge and so the original integral does not converge. The value of that integral does not exist. Similarly, the second limit does not exist, the integral from which it comes does not converge, and the original integral does not converge.* This paragraph is wrong, although I think everything else in the post is right. Why would you say the limits do not exist when they are in fact infinite?

Comment: @Allawonder : For a limit to exist, its limit points must be a point in the space.  Neither $\infty$ nor $-\infty$ are points in $\Bbb{R}$, so no limit (in the calculus of real numbers) which exists takes those values.  The behaviours "increases, forever beyond any bound" and "decreases, forever beyond any bound" are both common patterns and are useful to specify.  Consequently, using the more specific labels "$\infty$" and "$-\infty$" for nonexistent limits exhibiting these behaviours is of use.  Nevertheless these two labels for limits represent particular kinds of failing to exist.

Comment: @EricTowers Oh, well, provided there's a tacit agreement we're working in $\mathbf R.$ I always think instead in terms of the extended real line $[-\infty,+\infty].$